# Generating YAML by parsing systemd-resolve output

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, yaml

I am trying to create 2 arrays with bash.

array1 called DNSSERVERS : with all DNS Servers; output should be like this: `1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4`

and

array2 called DNSSERVERSSEARCH.with all DNS Domain; output should be like this: `local.domain.net,domain.net`

all this information comes from: `systemd-resolve --status`.

Then I would like to put this array to a bash script called: `bounding-netplan.sh`

And the things is that today we have 4 DNS Server and 2 DNS domain.
but tomorrow it could be 1 DNS Server and 4 DNS Domain. The script must be flexible.

I tried to set with awk. but without success.

anyone can help me on this. will be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
# systemd-resolve --status
Global
     DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                  2.2.2.2
                  3.3.3.3
                  4.4.4.4
      DNS Domain: local.domain.net
                  domain.net
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
                  20.172.in-addr.arpa
                  21.172.in-addr.arpa
                  22.172.in-addr.arpa
                  23.172.in-addr.arpa
                  24.172.in-addr.arpa
                  25.172.in-addr.arpa
                  26.172.in-addr.arpa
                  27.172.in-addr.arpa
                  28.172.in-addr.arpa
                  29.172.in-addr.arpa
                  30.172.in-addr.arpa
                  31.172.in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test
```

## cat bounding-netplan.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

MAJORRELEASE=$( lsb_release -sr | cut -d\. -f1 )
STROS=$( lsb_release -si )


# Ubuntu 18.04
if [ $STROS == Ubuntu ] && [ $MAJORRELEASE -ge 18 ] ; then
  if [ -d /etc/netplan ]; then
    DNSSERVERS=``
    DNSSERVERSSEARCH=``

    cat <<EOF | tee /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
     switchports:
       match: {name: "enp*"}
   bonds:
     bond0:
       interfaces: [switchports]
       addresses: [${IP}]
       gateway4: ${ROUTE}
       nameservers:
         search: [${DNSSERVERSSEARCH}] 
         addresses: [${DNSSERVERS}]
EOF

  fi
fi
```

Comment: You need to write your own parser for the data. For each line, check if the line is `KEY:` then add the value to the specified array if KEY = something.

Comment: You `tried to set with awk. but without success.` and now you have tried to set with shell but without success. Go back to trying to do it with awk as it's the better approach (awk is the tool that shell calls to manipulate text) and ask questions about **that** if you need help.

Comment: I have an idea. i am trying to figure out with awk using BEGIN and END. but the format is not easy for me .. so probably i will remove format to 1 line. using tr -d '\n' .

Comment: Waitaminute, you're *consuming* the output from `systemd-resolve`? You realize it has programmatic interfaces *designed* for machines to parse? f/e, see `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` for output in traditional (stable!) `resolv.conf` format; because its whole purpose is compatibility, you have some certainty that formatting isn't going to suddenly change between releases as `--status` output can.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy !! you absolutely right. I am getting information from `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` now. many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think found a way here:

```bash
$ systemd-resolve --status | sed -e 's#[\t ]##g' | awk -F\: 'BEGIN{section=""}{if($2!=""){section=$1; print $1" "$2}else {print section" "$1}}' | awk '{if($1=="DNSServers") print $2}' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's#,$##'

1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4
```

The former only work when it's only IPv4, this work for both IPv4 and IPv6:

```bash
$ systemd-resolve --status | sed -e 's/: /=/' | sed -e 's#[\t ]##g' | awk -F= 'BEGIN{section=""}{if($2!=""){section=$1; print $1" "$2}else {print section" "$1}}' | awk '{if($1=="DNSServers") print $2}' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's#,$##'

8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8,fd80::7a98:e8ff:fe46:4328,fe80::1
```